# Custom Google Bubble Chart Tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a custom tooltip for my Google Bubble Chart that displays content on mouseover and then goes away on mouseout.  Right now it's only displaying the "standard" Google tooltip content.  There is another question on here where I got the JS from but I cannot comment on it since my rep is not high enough.  My code and jsfiddle are below.  All help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Data1','Data2','Data3','Data4','Data5','Data6','Data7','Data8'],
          ['This is Data1',7500,2757,'This is Data 4',4,'This is Data 6','This is Data 8',330],
          ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Test Title',
      hAxis: {title: 'Test hAxis'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Test vAxis'},
      bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
      $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
          mouseX = e.pageX;
          mouseY = e.pageY;
      });

    function handler1(e){
      var x = mouseX;
      var y = mouseY - 130;
      var a = 1;
      var b = 2;
      $('#custom_tooltip').html('<div>Value of A is'+a+' and value of B is'+b+'</div>').css({'top':y,'left':x}).fadeIn('slow');
      }

    function handler2(e){
      $('#custom_tooltip').fadeOut('fast');
      }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', handler1);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', handler2);

  }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/erp5a/

Comment: You are missing the custom tooltip div.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/erp5a/1/

Comment: You do it wrong. Tooltips of Google charts can be easily customized by using the default API: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Comment: Thank you asgallant!  You have made it work the way I needed.  vorrtex, if you look at the bottom of that page it states that the Bubble Charts do not support customized tooltips.

Comment: +1 @asgallant good reference even though the fact being Google Charts don't support custom tooltips AFAIK.

Comment: Most Visualization API charts do support custom tooltips; BubbleCharts are one of the few that do not.

Comment: asgallant's comment should be the accepted answer